# I want to make reverse order of Column using single formula, How can I make it

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I want to make column in reverse order, I tried to do it, but it is taking blank value also. I just want the sheet to check every row and flip the row.

You will understand what I want from this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WpK3v4fUagbluJev6Oy1BxicH8l9mbjwOrvn4ayZcYQ/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A2:D3&"♦"), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A2:D3)), 0),,999)), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]